# Simple Ember component test with computed properties

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-qunit, ember-testing

I know this should be simple, I'm just not doing something right, and haven't found the example to mimic nor I guess do I fully understand what should go inside an `Ember.run()`

Here is my component code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  isGreen: function() {
    if (!status) { return ''; }
    return status.toUpperCase() === 'G';
  }.property('status')
});
```

My component template:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-green {{if isGreen 'active'}}">
    <input checked="checked" name="status" value="G" type="radio"/> Green
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-yellow {{if isYellow 'active'}}">
      <input name="status" value="Y" type="radio"/> Yellow
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-red {{if isRed 'active'}}">
      <input name="status" value="R" type="radio"/> Red
  </label>
</div>
```

And in my test:

```
test('status sets active class on the correct button', function(assert) {
  expect(3);
  var component = this.subject();

  //Green status
  Ember.run(function() {
    component.set('status', 'G');
  })
  equal(this.$().find('.btn-green.active').length, 1, 'When status is green, the green button has the active class');
```

I have three of these tests, one for each of three different statuses. If I have just one test, I don't need the to wrap `component.set()` in an `Ember.run()` in order for the test to pass. But if I have all three tests, I get this error:

> You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's
>   autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects
>   in a run

But if I do put each of my `component.set()` calls in a run loop, then my tests fail due to the `equal` assertion expecting 1 and getting 0. I'm sure this is due to a lack of understanding on my part, but either the `set()` isn't running, or else the component gets re-rendered in the assertion and thus doesn't know that the status property was already set. I've been reading docs and googling for an hour, and haven't found a solution yet (and more beneficially, an explanation).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.get('status')`? As your code stands, it most likely will cause a run-time error that `status` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

@torazaburo: ***Facepalm*** For some reason the test passed when it was just one, which I think might have been a false positive due to something in the template. But of course you're right.

I should have been using `this.get(status)`. Newbie error!